# Unable to attach Public IP to Azure windows VM (created using for_each) in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure

I use terraform version : v0.14.6
I have been trying to attach a public IP to a Azure windows VM that is being created by for_each condition in terraform. I can't figure out how to attach the public IP that is created on a different module again using for_each to my module for Windows VM creation. Below is the script I am using :

```
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  count = local.resourcegroup_state_exists == false ? 1 : 0
  name  = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "this" {
  for_each             = var.windows_vm_nics
  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  virtual_network_name = each.value.vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
}


resource "azurerm_public_ip" "public_ip" {
  for_each            = var.publicIp_variable
  name                = each.value["name"]
  ip_version          = each.value["ip_version"]
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  allocation_method     = each.value["allocation"]
  sku                 = each.value["sku"]
  domain_name_label   = each.value["public_ip_dns"]
  idle_timeout_in_minutes  = each.value["idle_timeout_in_minutes"]
  zones               =  each.value["zone"]
  tags = var.publicIp_tags
}

locals {
  resourcegroup_state_exists = false
  public_ip_exists     ={ for k, v in var.windows_vm_nics : k => v if lookup(v, "use_existing_public_ip ", false) == true }
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "windows_nics" {
  for_each                      = var.windows_vm_nics
  name                          = each.value.name
  resource_group_name           = local.resourcegroup_state_exists == true ? var.resource_group_name : data.azurerm_resource_group.this.0.name
  location                      = local.resourcegroup_state_exists == true ? var.resource_group_name : data.azurerm_resource_group.this.0.location
  internal_dns_name_label       = lookup(each.value, "internal_dns_name_label", null) #integration testing needs to be done once DNS is created
  enable_ip_forwarding          = lookup(each.value, "enable_ip_forwarding", null)
  enable_accelerated_networking = lookup(each.value, "enable_accelerated_networking", null)
  dns_servers                   = lookup(each.value, "dns_servers", null) #integration testing needs to be done once DNS is created

  dynamic "ip_configuration" {
    for_each = coalesce(each.value.nic_ip_configurations, [])
    content {
      name                          = coalesce(ip_configuration.value.name, format("%s00%d-ip", each.value.name, index(each.value.nic_ip_configurations, ip_configuration.value) + 1))
      subnet_id                     = lookup(data.azurerm_subnet.this, each.key)["id"]
      private_ip_address_allocation = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "static_ip", null) == null ? "dynamic" : "static"
      private_ip_address            = lookup(ip_configuration.value, "static_ip", null)
      public_ip_address_id          = lookup(each.value, "use_existing_public_ip", false) == true ? lookup(azurerm_public_ip.public_ip[each.value["existing_public_ip_name"]],each.key)["id"] :null #[each.value["existing_public_ip_name"]]
      primary = index(each.value.nic_ip_configurations, ip_configuration.value) == 0 ? true : false
    }
  }

  tags = local.tags
  depends_on = [ azurerm_public_ip.public_ip ]
}
```

the below is the variable file I have created for the same:

```
        variable "windows_virtual_machine" {
  type = map(object({
    name                                 = string
    vm_size                              = string
    zone                                 = string
    assign_identity                      = bool
    availability_set_key                 = string
    vm_nic_keys                          = list(string)
    source_image_reference_publisher     = string
    source_image_reference_offer         = string
    source_image_reference_sku           = string
    source_image_reference_version       = string
    os_disk_name                         = string
    storage_os_disk_caching              = string
    storage_account_type                 = string
    disk_size_gb                         = number
    write_accelerator_enabled            = bool
    license_type                         = string
    ultra_ssd_enabled                    = bool
    custom_data_path                     = string
    custom_data_args                     = map(string)
  }))
  description = "Map containing Windows VM objects"
  default     = {}
}
```

I believe `public_ip_address_id          = lookup(each.value, "use_existing_public_ip", false) == true ? lookup(azurerm_public_ip.public_ip[each.value["existing_public_ip_name"]],each.key)["id"] :null #[each.value["existing_public_ip_name"]]`  is where I need to make the modification but not quite sure what is going wrong. Terraform doesn't throw any errors while running the script but it is not attaching the public IP either.

Below is the variable file for nic:

```
    variable "windows_vm_nics" {
  type = map(object({
    name                          = string
    subnet_name                   = string
    vnet_name                     = string
    networking_resource_group     = string
    internal_dns_name_label       = string
    enable_ip_forwarding          = bool
    enable_accelerated_networking = bool
    use_existing_public_ip               = bool
    existing_public_ip_name              = string
    existing_public_ip_rg_name           = string
    dns_servers                   = list(string)
    nic_ip_configurations = list(object({
      name      = string
      static_ip = string
    }))
  }))
  description = "Map containing Windows VM NIC objects"
  default     = {}
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 public_ip_address_id          = lookup(each.value, "use_existing_public_ip", false) == true ? lookup(azurerm_public_ip.public_ip[each.value["existing_public_ip_name"]],each.key)["id"] :null #[each.value["existing_public_ip_name"]]
|----------------
| azurerm_public_ip.public_ip is object with 1 attribute "public_IP_1"
| each.value["existing_public_ip_name"] is "Windows-PIP"
```

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

The below is the tfvars I have  used :

```
resource_group_name     = "rg-terraform"
resource_group_location = "East US"
publicIp_variable = {
  "public_IP_1" = {
    name    = "Windows-PIP"
    ip_version       = "IPv4"
    allocation       = "Static"
    sku              = "Standard"
    public_ip_dns    =  null
    idle_timeout_in_minutes     =  null 
    zone             =  null 
}
}


windows_vm_nics = {
     nic1 = {
        name                      = "neudesicdemovm01-nic1"
        subnet_name               = "subnet1"
        vnet_name                 = "terraform_vnet"
        networking_resource_group = null
        use_existing_public_ip               = true
        existing_public_ip_name          ="Windows-PIP"
        existing_public_ip_rg_name           ="rg-terraform"
        internal_dns_name_label       = null
        enable_ip_forwarding          = null 
        enable_accelerated_networking = null 
        dns_servers                   = null
        nic_ip_configurations = [
          {
            static_ip = null
            name      = "ip-config"
          }
        ]   
    } 
    }
```

Comment: What is the variable file for windows_vm_nics?

Comment: @NancyXiong I have added the the variable file

Comment: @NancyXiong I made changes according to your answer but I am getting an error. I have added the new changes in the post.

Comment: @NancyXiong I have updated the question with the full template

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have `public_ip_address_id          = lookup(each.value, "use_existing_public_ip", false) == true ? lookup(data.azurerm_public_ip.this, each.key)["id"]` in the `resource "azurerm_network_interface" "windows_nics"` with `for_each                      = var.windows_vm_nics`. However, there are no `use_existing_public_ip` attibutes in the `variable "windows_vm_nics"`. You may try to add it.

For example:

```
variable "windows_vm_nics" {
  type = map(object({
    name                      = string
    subnet_name               = string
    vnet_name                 = string
    networking_resource_group = string
    internal_dns_name_label       = string
    enable_ip_forwarding          = bool
    enable_accelerated_networking = bool
    dns_servers                   = list(string)
    use_existing_public_ip               = bool   # add this
    nic_ip_configurations = list(object({
      name      = string
      static_ip = string
    }))
  }))
  description = "Map containing Windows VM NIC objects"
  default     = {}
}
```